# How we change datagridview header name?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I write a code in windows form application for change the header name.

```
            DataGridViewCellStyle columnHeaderStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
            columnHeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Beige;
            columnHeaderStyle.Font = new Font("Bookman Old Style", 8, FontStyle.Bold);
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle = columnHeaderStyle;

            dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
            dataGridView1.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Item Code";
            dataGridView1.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Item Name";
```

But when I run this code there shows a error. "`Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index`"
How Can I solve it?

Comment: it's obviously that your `dataGridView1` doesn't have any column.

Comment: Check the data bindings and that there is actually columns in the grid. Additionally, you should set this on the properties of the grid columns, rather than in code (Unless you are generating it on the fly)

Comment: Yes. There is no column. I want to create a blank datagridview. I insert data in it. And when I press save button then the data will save to the database. So How can I create it?

Comment: @KingKing : How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @DanielDawes:How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index

You get this error because your datagridview doesn't have any columns and you are trying to access a column at index 0 in the following code

```
dataGridView1.Columns[0]
```

As i go through your comments you have mentioned that you create an ***empty datagridview and then assign datasource*** to it. If that is the case then you need to access columns after assigning datasource. You also need to make sure that autogeneratecolumns = true

or if you want to ***create an unbound DataGridView*** The following code example demonstrates how to create an unbound [DataGridView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.columns.aspx);

Though to avoid exception and make sure that you have columns in your datagridview. You can first do this

```
if(dataGridView1.Columns.Count> 2)
{
     //your code
}
```